# "Invalid credentials" for Omniauth-facebook 2.0.0 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I know there are lots of topics concerning the issue, however none of the suggested fixes worked for me so I had to ask.
So I am using Omniauth-facebook 2.0.0 and Omniauth 1.2.0. Here is how the Gemfile looks like:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem "omniauth-facebook"
```

Moreover in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           :image_size => {:width => '800', :height => '800'}
end
```

Everything works in `local`, but not in `production`. And yes, I have checked the `App_id` and `App_secret` in production and they are all fine. My Facebook app has permissions for `public_info`(this is all I need for now).
As for Facebook, when I execute the action, the following url is returned:

`https://www.noombers.com/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.noombers.com%2Fen%2Fauthentications&strategy=facebook`

Please help. Have been busting my head over this for too long now.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Make sure that the gem 'omniauth-facebook' is at version '2.0.0' in production. (specifying that in the gem file).

Comment: Hey, mate, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: I honestly don't remember that clearly anymore. It was more than a year ago so its kinda vague in my mind. It was either the gem versions or something that has to do with SSL, so 1) make sure you specify the gem versions in your `gemfile` and check what versions are running in production. 2) Facebook expects a secure connection so if you don't have SSL it won't work. They changed a lot of things in the last year so now you even need an SSL for testing on local. Maybe it is something related to that.